# NSDate is not transformed correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to transform a datestring into another format. I am doing it like this.

```
NSLog(@"datestring is NOW %@",_dayObject.p_date);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:_dayObject.p_date];
NSLog(@"date transformed %@",date);
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd/MM/YYYY"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
NSString *dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"datestring is AFTER %@",dateStr);
```

But this is what I get from my NSLOGs

```
2013-04-18 08:43:36.181 mosaqua2[9629:907] datestring is NOW 2013-05-04
2013-04-18 08:43:36.184 mosaqua2[9629:907] date transformed 2013-01-03 23:00:00 +0000
2013-04-18 08:43:36.184 mosaqua2[9629:907] datestring is AFTER donderdag, 03/01/2013
```

What I want it to be is

```
Saterday, 04/05/2013
```

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use my this bellow custom method for convert Date Format ...

```
-(NSString *)changeDateFormat:(NSString*)stringDate dateFormat:(NSString*)dateFormat getwithFormat:(NSString *)getwithFormat{


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];

    dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:getwithFormat];

    NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
    return convertedString;
}
```

and use it like bellow...

```
NSString *strSDate = [self changeDateFormat:_dayObject.p_date dateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd" getwithFormat:@"EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSLog(@"datestring is AFTER %@",strSDate);
```

See [My Blog](http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/) with this post...

Answer (score 1):

Check this.....

```
NSLog(@"datestring is NOW ==>> %@", _dayObject.p_date);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString: _dayObject.p_date];
NSLog(@"date transformed ==>> %@",date);
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
NSString *dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"datestring is AFTER ==>> %@",dateStr);
```

- **OUTPUT:~**

  datestring is NOW ==>> 2013-05-04

  date transformed ==>> 2013-05-04 00:00:00 +0000

  datestring is AFTER ==>> Saturday, 04/05/2013

Answer (score 0):

Check the character case of parameters

```
NSLog(@"datestring is NOW %@",_dayObject.p_date);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"]; //MODIFIED
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:_dayObject.p_date];
NSLog(@"date transformed %@",date);
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy"]; //MODIFIED
NSString *dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"datestring is AFTER %@",dateStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try ..this it will work to get the week name

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"eeee"];
 NSCalendar * cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSUInteger numWeekdays = [cal maximumRangeOfUnit:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit].length;
 NSDateComponents * comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
for( NSUInteger day = 1; day <= numWeekdays; day++ ){
[comp setWeekday:day];
[comp setWeek:0];
NSDate * date = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];

NSString * dayName = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@", dayName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing all right except `setTimeZone` , comment that you will get your output.

```
NSLog(@"datestring is NOW %@",_dayObject.p_date);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:_dayObject.p_date];
NSLog(@"date transformed %@",date);
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd/MM/YYYY"];
//[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]]; //NOT NEEDED
NSString *dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"datestring is AFTER %@",dateStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this : "YYYY"

To : "yyyy"

Reason for the error,

> It's a common mistake to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year
>   whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO
>   year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same
>   number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the
>   calendar year.